# DevDemon Updater - can't find "EllisLab" folder

Tags: ee2-upgrades, devdemon, devdemon-updater

Updating an older site, and I'm getting an error using the DevDemon Updater (v3.2.15), while trying to bring a site from 2.5.5 to 2.8.1

It stops during the update process on an error. And that message says: `Unexpected server response, probably a php error. Show Error` - which I click through, it says this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: copy(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/sitehomedir/blog/system/expressionengine/cache/updater/1407520245_589541/system/EllisLab): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: libraries/updater_transfer.php
Line Number: 827
{"success":"yes","body":""}
```

Not sure why it's looking for an Ellislab folder in /system/ - Is this a bug in the updater? Or something with my code?

Caveat: my site is in a subfolder (i.e. mysite.com/blog/ ) All the other functions work fine, but I just can't get EE to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went poking in the code for the plugin and found the reference to EllisLab - I removed the updater and installed an earlier version (v3.2.11). And that version was able to update my site to 2.8.1 without any issues appearing.